# Browser hangs when debugging Flash

Tags: debugging, firefox, browser, flash

Since the latest update to Firefox 3.6.13 I can no longer debug flash apps.  If I have the debug flash player installed, it hangs when loading my application, and never connects to the debugger.

I'm running Flash Debug 10.2 (latest one).

I've tried uninstalling / reinstalling, but I get the same experience.

When the page loads, the browser hangs, 10+ seconds later, the page continues.  It happens on my application as well as sites like Hulu.

Anyone else have similar issues?

I already disabled the dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.npswf32.dll and set timeoutSecs to -1.

--EDIT--
This issue seems to happen in all browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome) with Flash Debug player 10.1 or 10.2.  I'm not quite sure what the issue might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow my hosts entry for "localhost" got mangled when editing the file.  This caused the debugger to look for a debug host on another machine.  It then waited for the timeout before continuing to work.

Fixing the localhost issue fixed my debugging issue.